# Plot of function composition by coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, axis

I'm try to plot the function $2^f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is a piecewise function. $f$ is given by a set of coordinates, i.e:

```
\addplot[blue,line width=1pt,rounded corners=1pt] coordinates {
(-6,4)
(-2,0)
(-1,0)
(0,-3)
(1,1)
(2,0)
(3,1)
};
```

Is there a way to get $2^f(x)$ using the given coordinates?

Here the code and the output:

### Current

[image]

But I aiming to get the following plot:

### Goal

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
grid=both,
width=7cm, height=7cm,
axis x line=middle, 
axis y line=middle, 
samples=100,
ymin=-6.2, ymax=6.2,
xmin=-6.2, xmax=6.2,
domain=-6:6,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel={$y$},
axis equal image
]
\addplot[blue,line width=1pt,rounded corners=1pt] coordinates {
(-6,4)
(-2,0)
(-1,0)
(0,-3)
(1,1)
(2,0)
(3,1)
} node[right]{$f(x)$};
\addplot[red,line width=1pt,rounded corners=1pt] coordinates {
(-6,{2^4})
(-2,{2^0})
(-1,{2^0})
(0,{2^(-10)})
(1,{2^1})
(2,{2^0})
(3,{2^1})
} node[right]{$2^{f(x)}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way such piecewise plot
can be constructed in `Asymptote`:

```
// 
// "gpiecewise.asy"
// 
// run 
//   asy gpiecewise.asy
// 
// to get a standalone 
//   "gpiecewise.pdf"
// 
settings.tex="pdflatex";
import graph;
import math;

import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(8pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}"+"\usepackage{amsmath}"
  +"\usepackage{amsfonts}"+"\usepackage{amssymb}");

pen linePen =darkblue+  .8bp;
pen line2Pen=orange+    .8bp;
pen grayPen =gray(0.3)+0.5bp;

real scx=0.25, scy=1;
int xCells=38, yCells=22;
add(shift(-25*scx,-5*scy)*scale(scx,scy)*grid(xCells,yCells,paleblue+0.2bp));

real pagew=9cm,pageh=yCells/xCells*9cm;
size(pagew,pageh,IgnoreAspect);

real xmin=-6,xmax=3;
real ymin=-4,ymax=16;
xaxis(xmin,xmax,RightTicks(Step=1,step=0.5,OmitTick(0)),above=true,p=grayPen);
yaxis(ymin,ymax,LeftTicks (Step=2,step=1,  OmitTick(0)),above=true,p=grayPen);

pair[]p ={(-6, 4),(-2, 0),(-1, 0),( 0,-3),( 1, 1),( 2, 0),( 3, 1),};
real[]px=map(xpart, p);
real[]py=map(ypart, p);

real fl(real x, pair a, pair b){
  return a.y*(1-(x-a.x)/(b.x-a.x))+b.y*(x-a.x)/(b.x-a.x);
}

pair f(real x){
  int k=search(px,x);
  return (x,fl(x,p[k],p[k+1]));
}

pair f2(real x){
  int k=search(px,x);
  return (x,2^fl(x,p[k],p[k+1]));
}

real eps=1e-7;
draw(graph(f, xmin,xmax-eps,200),linePen);
draw(graph(f2,xmin,xmax-eps,200),line2Pen);

label("$f(x)$",f(-5.5)     ,plain.NE);
label("$2^{f(x)}$",f2(-5.5),plain.NE);
```

[image]

If you really need a `TikZ` code, you can translate the `asy` source
to `.svg` output with

```
asy -f svg gpiecewise.asy
```

then convert it to TikZ with [svg2tikz](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz):

```
svg2tikz --standalone gpiecewise.svg > gpiecewise.tex
```

and get `gpiecewise.tex` file with `TikZ` code.

Answer (score 1):

### Full PGF-TikZ solution

I was searching a full PGF-TikZ solution. I got it by the following ideas and the help of `pgfplots` and `pgfplotstable` packages.

1. A straight line function between `A(a1,a2)` and `B(b1,b2)` is defined (as [g.kov's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/568041/79437)) by

> f(x)=(x-a1)/(a2-a1)*(b2-b1)+b2

2. To plot "piece by piece" the composition function `g(f(x))` (here `g(x)=2^x`). That's means for *n* points/coordinates *n-1* pieces each having domain `\xstart:\xend`

   ```
   \addplot[domain=\xstart:\xend,mark=none,smooth, red]
   {2^((x-\xstart)/(\xend-\xstart)*(\yend-\ystart)+\ystart))};
   ```
3. Getting the values to plot by

   ```
   \pgfplotstablegetelem{<row>}{<column name>}
   ```

   inside `\addplot`.
4. Plot all of the pieces by a loop which allows to access simultaneously at two rows of `\points` where `\points` is the data table. One can reach this by adding the second counter `\second`.

   ```
   \foreach \piece[count=\second] in {0,...,\numberofrows}
   ```
5. Stop the plot's loop by check the counter `\numberofrows`.

   ```
   \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\points}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numberofrows}{\pgfplotsretval-2}
   ```

Notice that one can struggled to read a table by `foreach` inside `axis`. Moreover the `pgfplotstable`manual suggest to avoid to use `\pgfplotstablegetelem` inside loop (p. 62). Anyway my code seams to be fast enough. Anyone who either have suggestions or can improve the code is welcome.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

% An arbitrary set of points
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
X,Y
-6,4
-3,0
-1,0
0,-3
2,1
4,0
5,1
}\points

% The (integer) number of points
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\points}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numberofrows}{\pgfplotsretval-2}


\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\pgfplotsset{table/col sep = comma}
\begin{axis}[
width=7cm, height=7cm,
axis x line=middle, 
axis y line=middle, 
samples=100,
ymin=-3.2, ymax=4.2,
xmin=-6.2, xmax=6.5,
domain=-6:6,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel={$y$},
]
% the original piecewise function f
\addplot[blue,mark=none] table[x=X,y=Y] from \points;

% the composition function g(f(x))=2^x
\foreach \piece[count=\second] in {0,...,\numberofrows}
{
% set the needed values
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\piece}{X}\of\points
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xstart}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\piece}{Y}\of\points
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ystart}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\second}{X}\of\points
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xend}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\second}{Y}\of\points
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yend}{\pgfplotsretval}
% plot the piece g(f(x))
\addplot[domain=\xstart:\xend,mark=none,smooth, red]
{2^((x-\xstart)/(\xend-\xstart)*(\yend-\ystart)+\ystart)};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Onother composition for fun**

```
% a second composition for fun with g(x)=2*sin(x)
\foreach \piece[count=\second] in {0,...,\numberofrows}
{
% set the needed values
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\piece}{X}\of\points
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xstart}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\piece}{Y}\of\points
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ystart}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\second}{X}\of\points
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xend}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\second}{Y}\of\points
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yend}{\pgfplotsretval}
% plot the piece g(f(x))
\addplot[domain=\xstart:\xend,mark=none,smooth, orange]
{2*sin(deg((x-\xstart)/(\xend-\xstart)*(\yend-\ystart)+\ystart))};
}
```

[image]